# Which is this facebook poll application?

Tags: facebook

Can anyone please tell how to add the following kind of poll in a facebook business page...

http://www.facebook.com/hm?v=app_60082431253

It shows in the wall as well as in its own tab.. I can vote from the wall, comment and Like.. excellent feature it is.. but no information about it anywhere :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not available from facebook anymore. I think its because of some of the privacy concerns people have about this app.

Comment: Then how does it still available for HM, Coca Cola, Dell and all?

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge, it was a custom-made Poll that Facebook previously made for huge brands willing to pay $ 10, 000 and up. It is no longer available.

However Appbistro.com has a similar Tab app that may fulfill your needs:

[Poll Tab](http://appbistro.com/products/poll)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Facebook developer and I just created a Facebook app that looks like the one you point out. It lets you create a poll and publish it on your Facebook page. Try it out and let me know what you think of it :

http://apps.facebook.com/my-polls/

Comment: I just tried this one and found it was the best designed and most flexible of the ones I could find, well done.